# making qthread as singleton consumes lots of CPU load

Tags: qt, qthread

im trying to have the scope of the qthread in different object of my project. so i tried to make the thread a singleton . it is a DBUS interface im using as a client.

this is my implemented code .
.h

```
class ClientDBUSThread : public QThread
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    static ClientDBUSThread *getInstance();

    void messageReceived(QString );

private:
    ClientDBUSThread();
    static ClientDBUSThread *instance;
    static QMutex instanceMutex;
    void run();

signals:
    void signalReceivedInDBUS(QString);

public Q_SLOTS:
    void mySlot(QString);

    void stop();

private:
    DemoIf* client ;
    QMutex m_mutex;
    bool m_stop;

};
```

and .cpp

```
#include "ClienDBusThread.h"

#include <QMap>

ClientDBUSThread *ClientDBUSThread::instance(0);
QMutex ClientDBUSThread::instanceMutex;

ClientDBUSThread *ClientDBUSThread::getInstance()
{
    if (!instance) {
        QMutexLocker instanceMutexLocker(&instanceMutex);
        if (!instance) {
            instance = new ClientDBUSThread();
        }
    }

    return instance;
}


ClientDBUSThread::ClientDBUSThread()
{
    m_stop = false;
    client = new DemoIf("com.nokia.Demo", "/", QDBusConnection::sessionBus(), 0);
    connect(client, SIGNAL(LateEvent(QString)), this, SLOT(mySlot(QString)));
    QDBusConnection cnn= client->connection();

    qDebug()<<"is the DBUS gets connected:"<<cnn.isConnected();

    const QMap<QString, QVariant> hi;
    client->SayHello("HELLO THERE HOW ARE YOU", hi);

    client->SayBye();
}

void ClientDBUSThread::run()
{

    while (1) {

            QMutexLocker locker(&m_mutex);
            if (m_stop) break;

    }
}

void ClientDBUSThread::stop()
{

    QMutexLocker locker(&m_mutex);
    m_stop=true;

    client->SayBye();
}

void ClientDBUSThread::messageReceived(QString message)
{
    const QMap<QString, QVariant> hi;
    client->SayHello(message, hi);
}



void ClientDBUSThread::mySlot(QString data)
{

    emit signalReceivedInDBUS(data);
}
```

while declaring the object like

> theDBUSThread = ClientDBUSThread::getInstance();
>   it is fine but while starting the thread
>
> theDBUSThread->start();

the CPU load is exceeding 100% of the PC . im starting the thread only in main class . the rest class im just declaring and using the signals the DBUS receives .

Comment: use `qDebug() << QThread::currentThreadId();` to check if your code runs in a separated thread or not

Comment: of course the code is running as separate thread . it is not blocking my GUI flow .and also to relive my suspicion on gui i comment the thread and  check only the GUI . it is ok .. only the thread gives the CPU load larger ..

Comment: i havent overwritten a QThreads's run method so i can only assume that the problem is in your while loop. i usually use a worker object that gets moved to specific thread using `QObject::moveToThread()`.

Comment: Are you saying that if it's not a singleton it doesn't consume as much CPU?

Comment: As @Zaiborg stated, your run-loop will keep the cpu busy. Set up a QThread::msleep() and depending on your needs set up a processEvents() call too.

Comment: Are you saying that if it's not a singleton it doesn't consume as much CPU?  yes .. and as if i put msleep the cpu load is decreased drastically . msleep(100) .. but is it a good solution ..?

Comment: This is not a problem of the singleton, this is a problem of the infinite loop running without any break. I advise you to use msleep(), but keep it low at ``msleep(5)``. This will already save a lot process time. It depends on your needs. You want to have it realtime then leave it or run only for 1 msec. You just need it to read and display some information? 50 msec is enough. Having a fair trade between both a msleep for 5-10 msec worked fine for us most of the time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only your run() loop code gets executed in the thread. How do you expect that code runs anything else without an event loop running the slots when they are triggered?

You should not subclass from QThread in this case.

Instead, derive your class from QObject.

```
class ClientDBUSThread : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    static ClientDBUSThread *getInstance();

    void messageReceived(QString );

private:
    ClientDBUSThread();
    static ClientDBUSThread *instance;
    static QThread * thread;
    static QMutex instanceMutex;
    //void run();  //removed

signals:
    void signalReceivedInDBUS(QString);

public Q_SLOTS:
    void startup();
    void mySlot(QString);
    void stop();

private:
    DemoIf* client ;
    QMutex m_mutex;
    bool m_stop;

};
```

Create a static QThread instance in GetInstance() along with your main class. Then move the latter to the thread:

```
ClientDBUSThread *ClientDBUSThread::getInstance()
{
    if (!instance) {
        QMutexLocker instanceMutexLocker(&instanceMutex);
        if (!instance) {
            //You will need to destroy these somewhere
            instance = new ClientDBUSThread();
            thread = new QThread();
            instance->moveToThread(thread);
            connect(thread, SIGNAL(started()), instance, SLOT(startup()));
            //the thread is not started yet, you need to thread->start() somewhere
        }
    }

    return instance;
}
```

Then do your startup jobs not in constructor, but in startup

```
void ClientDBUSThread::ClientDBUSThread()
{
    //I supposed that last argument of DemoIf constructor
    //is the pointer to parent. It may be a good idea to parent it with this,
    //So I replaced 0 by this
    client = new DemoIf("com.nokia.Demo", "/", QDBusConnection::sessionBus(), this);
    connect(client, SIGNAL(LateEvent(QString)), this, SLOT(mySlot(QString)));
}


void ClientDBUSThread::startup()
{
    m_stop = false;
    QDBusConnection cnn= client->connection();

    qDebug()<<"is the DBUS gets connected:"<<cnn.isConnected();

    const QMap<QString, QVariant> hi;
    client->SayHello("HELLO THERE HOW ARE YOU", hi);

    client->SayBye();
}
```

Comment: @galinette, why use a static QThread? Is there likely to be more than one ClientDBusThread object?

Comment: Becauses he wants a singleton pattern, this was in the title. So yes, the autor wants only one ClientDBusThread.
In other cases, you would have a non static QThread per object, yes

Comment: so the client thread will start when the instance created in first time ..?

Comment: I agree with a lot of what you've answered, but I question why you'd even want a QThread inside the ClientDBusThread object. It appears that the main class is a ClientDBus object and the thread should be separated and moved out of that class. If there were multiple ClientDBus objects, than I can understand why you may want to have a static QThread object that they can share, but not in this case.

Comment: The QThread is not inside the object as it is static. It is just inside the ClientDBus namespace. Putting it outside the class is a matter of taste and project organization, and is not really relevant to the question

Comment: @galinette Yes, I meant inside the ClientDBus namespace. You call it a 'matter of taste', I'd say it's badly designed. Good design has loose coupling of objects and high cohesion. This design promotes low cohesion by including the QThread in the ClientDBus namespace. As I'm commenting on your answer and trying to help you improve it, it is completely relevant to the question, unless you think your answer bares no relevance itself.

Comment: Then post your answer instead of talking :)